# Print multidimensional list in python3

Tags: list, python-3.x, printing, multidimensional-array

I'm looking for a way to print a multidimensional lists in a specific way.
This is how my list full of int looks.

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

or

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
```

I want to print each element with a space and a comma between the two 'big' elements in the list. So for my example the output would be:

```
1 2 3, 4 5 6
```

and

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I use python 3.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [78]: L = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

In [79]: ', '.join([' '.join([str(i) for i in subl]) for subl in L])
Out[79]: '1 2 3, 4 5 6'

In [80]: L = [[1,2,3,4,5,6]]

In [81]: ', '.join([' '.join([str(i) for i in subl]) for subl in L])
Out[81]: '1 2 3 4 5 6'
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings can be easily joined using `'sep'.join(...)` with `sep` being the separator. Before joining the numbers of one part of the array, you need to convert them to strings. This can be easily done using a `map` function. For each element in `i` it applies the `str` function. After joining the numbers of each part separated with a space, you can join the parts to the final result.

```py
l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
print ', '.join([' '.join(map(str, i)) for i in l])
```

Output:

```
1 2 3, 4 5 6
```

**Note:** In Python 3 you need to call `print` with brackets: `print(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> ', '.join(map(lambda x: ' '.join(map(str, x)), l))
'1 2 3, 4 5 6'
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
>>> ', '.join(map(lambda x: ' '.join(map(str, x)), l))
'1 2 3 4 5 6'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]

for n in range(0, len(ls)):
    for m in range(0, len(ls[n])):
        print(str(ls[n][m]) + ' ', end='')
    if n < (len(ls)-1):
        print(', ', end='')
    else:
        print('')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.